# Is there a way in typescript to declare something like "string inside nested object"?

Tags: typescript

I have this use case. I have a generated constant that reproduces an JSON object structure:

Example:

JSON

```
{
   first: 'I am just first',
   second: {
        this: 'is',
        a: 'complex',
        object: {
           and: 'It could have more objects inside'
        }
   }
}
```

Generated const:

```
const MyConst = {
   first: 'first',
   second: {
      this: 'second.this',
      a: 'second.a',
      object: {
        and : 'second.object.and',
      }
   }
}
```

It is used to map the object to a kind safe structure so I can call `getInfoFromJson(MyConst.second.a)` and I get `complex` as return, and it updates thru an script when the JSON data (it is an static file) gets more keys.;

Now, the function signature for `getInfoFromJson` is

```
function getInfoFromJson(path: string): string {}
```

What I want is to say "take any string as parameter as long as it is contain inside MyConst".

I have not found how to do it, and for what I search looks like it is not possible but I thought I can take a shot and ask here.

Comment: @kaya3 without considering the type. I want to just be sure it takes whatever is inside `MyConst.any.path.here`, being it a string (like here) or maybe a number or another primitive as long it is part of `MyConst`

Comment: I see, so for example the result for `{ one: 'foo', two: { three: 23 } }` should be `string | number`?

Comment: it should be `23 | X | Y..etc` because `23` is *inside* that object

Comment: There is no such thing as "JSON object", or "JSON array". [JSON](https://json.org) is text, that in various programming languages is handled by the type `string`. JSON is a text representation of a data structure (that can be an object or an array or something else, a number for example). In order to manipulate the encoded data, the JSON needs to be parsed. The result of parsing is a data structure similar to the one used to generate the JSON. There is no JSON in your question. Just a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: @axiac eh, the specs (like [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) or [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259)) use "JSON text" to refer to the serialized text and "JSON value" to refer to the deserialized values to which JSON text corresponds.  The RFC itself says "JSON object" and "JSON array" to refer to specific JSON value types, so it's perhaps a bit too uncharitable to require such strict adherence to these particular rules of terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's assume that `MyConst` is strongly typed enough for the compiler to know the exact string values it contains.  The easiest way to do this is to define it with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions):

```
const MyConst = {
    first: 'first',
    second: {
        this: 'second.this',
        a: 'second.a',
        object: {
            and: 'second.object.and',
        }
    }
} as const;
```

If you inspect its type you'll see:

```
/* const MyConst: {
    readonly first: "first";
    readonly second: {
        readonly this: "second.this";
        readonly a: "second.a";
        readonly object: {
            readonly and: "second.object.and";
        };
    };
} */
```

---

Now you want a type function named something like `NestedValsMatching<T, V>` where given a types `T` and `V` you get a union of all the values inside `T`, no matter how deeply nested, that match `V`.  So ideally `NestedValsMatching<typeof MyConst, string>` would give you the union `"first" | "second.this" | "second.a" | "second.object.and"`.

The most straightforward implementation of `NestedValsMatching` would be recursive in a way that's currently not supported in TypeScript (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980)).  The compiler actually won't complain about it, but it does lead to some bad performance and other strangeness.  Here it is (but don't use it)

```
// ‍♂️ illegally recursive, don't use this ‍♀️ 
type RecursiveNestedValsMatching<T, V> =
    T extends V ? T :
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: RecursiveNestedValsMatching<T[K], V> }[keyof T] :
    never
```

Usually what I do in this situation is to unroll the circular type into some fixed but big-enough number of non-circular types, and then bail out at the end in some plausible way:

```
type NestedValsMatching<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM0<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM0<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM1<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM1<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM2<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM2<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM3<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM3<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM4<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM4<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM5<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM5<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM6<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM6<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM7<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM7<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM8<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM8<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVM9<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVM9<T, V> = T extends V ? T : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NVMX<T[K], V> }[keyof T] : never;
type NVMX<T, V> = Extract<T, V>;
```

That's more or less the same as the recursive definition, but it will only descend ~10 levels before bailing out.  Let's test it:

```
type MyConstPaths = NestedValsMatching<typeof MyConst, string>;
// type MyConstPaths = "first" | "second.this" | "second.a" | "second.object.and"
```

That's the type we wanted, and so we can now give your function a type:

```
declare function getInfoFromJson(path: MyConstPaths): string;
```

And use it:

```
getInfoFromJson(MyConst.second.a); // okay
getInfoFromJson(MyConst.second.object); // error!
getInfoFromJson(MyConst.second.object.and); // okay
getInfoFromJson("first"); // okay
getInfoFromJson("twelfth"); // error!
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwMLmjAvDA3gKBvmAMwEsAnaALhgHITypqAaPAiAU1DABMrcD+YUABbEIVau05cAdMNFMWAmAENxk8DOUKl+EACMAVhyi9FO-Mu5qOG6fqPAo0y1206Avmc-uVEGJ2gAbhwcAHoAKn9UWEQUSBNsM1I2ZS5wABsEIjJKGAAiOmg84P5k1Iys9StE8zK0sEzBETF8qpk5CGKzUpT6xtVWm25nLtreiph7Y1NzHvKGrJcqPLa7Q2NnblGPEoJ3YJ9w0JDQ0JhAXg3AOx3AWAJAITJAeD-zwBS988AKvZhidPS2AHNlL6yyWAAFdyMQAG5sRgwerUWDA9hNUQXV7nQDJe1droABMnuMBwUAQAAc2DAAEocUEQCFsABybGgbC4ADV-hA4MooMARGAfgAeAAq0KZAD4MGZ+TA2AAPKBsbh+JkwAD8MAlFHFkplcq4fimjmV2BgAG0ANIfMAwADWbAQIEIqoAulRySCwZC6Qzmaz2ZzuXz+aaHULRe4jdbbfb+Q6YOr+GA2JDSCECcSYB7ZV70myOVziDyBcGMKrNbL5TBFSq1cXpaWdZN1vqVVhjWa81abXbHVQaUy4AAGAWBwuh8OdqMxmDxxPBFMknv9gvl0WYCU17UKg1V1dast62BNlvm9sRrtp3sARkHJqDS5gI47kejVCnbFIM6Jc4vi5FRe3tY3lYTn+671g4+6GqaR6jo+3a9gATFeN4-veJ7js+Cavu+qbzghgq3iuJYgRWxZUMBu4NuBzaQW20GnvOADMiHDmGD6OhOL5vviH5nnAjF4T+BFrmWxFboR5FgQaVGthatFRrBcAACxMbeKFjk+k4YZxs48Up-HLtWO51iJQFiXWe6SYeNGsXJPEAKzKchLGoepHFYZ+cD2Xpv6mQBJEGf+oHGBZ1EydZTo8QAbA5IZOWp7GaW5kXfvpZFGZuJlCWZFHBdJx5qfJADs0V3rFj7xdOXHYb2RVeYJhm+aJmW6tlB4hXlME8QAHMVqllehFXafO3W1f5RHpaRPmBY2EG5bJ4XzgAnD1pVsf1mGVe5S0jalDUZfVU2UZZoXOfJAAay1zeV62Db250jQAojKpDKI4yXBBt8DINEAAKHJCH4mDpoyLJZj6ub5rOnaxNE0LQKQeY-MKwSnII3HQ-Ev3CAD+SFFAeQwAAPoMUiyM0+NEysQyaOTxO2HumxcHkIRcBw6TKMkRDAmAjjEOAMA-GwUAAJJgIQIAAGKkCAAC2ABSEDgAAFISf1UOj0CY-9ACUVBwwj70C8LosS1LcsK2Aivq04qzKFrgQwCjICWsoCA4IbIti5LMvy0rVvSKse52w7ZyvlLpAAIRu4LHsm975uW198T+1TaxgQzQeO87rvu8bXtm0rBQ5HjGdnE7LtR0bnumz7Ft5FAADubDpIQwh5CXkqkGH4cwEAA)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are able to construct a type like this:

```js
type Pairs = {
    'first': 'I am just first',
    'second.this': 'is',
    'second.a': 'complex',
    'second.object.and': 'It could have more objects inside'
}
```

In that case, we can use a string literal type like `'second.a'` to look up the string literal type `'complex'`.

It turns out that you can construct something close enough to `Pairs` to be useful. Essentially, given two types `S` and `T` with the same internal structure (i.e. they have the same properties, and if the values of those properties are objects then they recursively have the same internal structure), we want to pair up the "leaf" properties of `S` with the "leaf" properties of `T`.

My solution is below. As @jcalz notes in his answer, this is a recursively-defined mapped type, so here be dragons.

```js
type Pairs<S, T> = S extends PropertyKey ? Record<S, T> : {
    [K in keyof S & keyof T]: Pairs<S[K], T[K]>
}[keyof S & keyof T]

type Lookup<P, K extends PropertyKey> = P extends Record<K, infer U> ? U : never

type PairsKeys<P> = P extends Record<infer K, any> ? K : never
```

The `Pairs` type actually constructs a union type which looks like `Record<'first', ...> | Record<'second.this', ...> | ...`, so the `Lookup` type is needed to do the actual mapping from `'second.a'` to `'complex'`. The `PairsKeys` type is needed to construct a type for the keys, in order to reject invalid keys. But it does work:

```js
type Test = Pairs<typeof MyConst, typeof json>

function lookup<K extends PairsKeys<Test>>(key: K): Lookup<Test, K> {
    throw Error(); // not implemented here
}

// infers a: 'complex'
let a = lookup('second.a');

// type error on 'second.b'
let b = lookup('second.b');
```

All of that said, since `MyConst` is generated anyway, perhaps you have a way of generating the original `Pairs` as a constant too? That seems like it should be a better solution.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=42&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcMC8MDeAoG2YDMCWATtAFwwDkAkjAIYC28ArtHkdOQDRY4QCmoYACZlMOMTCgALfBDLkZnbuNpzQdAA4AbXgA9Fy7CABGcflBFKD2GkLmVYoRpsExJNAG68YdEIS-HTYCgIGHxIfEFecksxAF9LeNjaEIFoAG4MDFTYAFkATwBhcBZUURwCYnMKCvYuMT4BYXQYnCkZOQbwQQA6Noh9AxoO-i7umgHlALMLKzEbJvJOoW6poLGhCfF4uIwkmhTiqAyMKDz1LwAFGjYAHgBlDhgAFQA+FBg7mF0oXiEQi8IIHOhFOAGleHkYAB+GAAJRGhEE90erxgMxwAG1QaEwDAANYQkC4D4wABk+MJxKeAF0yFdbncsdSUUyXrsMQS8kSSeTOdyaZlTucYAAZEAgPGMdQ3C6PbHfX6Cf6A4FgiFvVAXL46H5-OEIpGgx5hXC8QgwACqbxhFrRMDAvE8hEFZ0u12I4LyEBlGpgWoVevhoERNxNZpgRtoYDy1ojdodTpdwqevBKfvd3qFvG5+SKkCgjyz3IQ4DZGFwjDAQXwSE04sl0vlOsV-wznu9KegLxeAApOWRQQBKMhiiVSm6dgsRt5lbBSQEAdxgAFFCIDCD3B2kYAB6Hf2kCwfAabR0X4-FySM28XaZPc403EFQUNRaXTRbSwGjvOtj9Q9xYRmWcYtzvfcsy+NdfBgJBAMabojA-XhYCMH96ylAClh6RDQKAA)